# Google Reverse-Geocoding issue, "zero results" for a valid location

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

So I am using googles geocoding api to get a location name(for coordinates) for my iphone application. The reason I am using a geocoding api instead of `CLGeocoder` is because I get inaccurate location names plus sometimes results are in the local language and not in english.

The problem is I get a "ZERO RESULTS" response for a valid location(default:Cupertino) but if I use the same url in the browser, I get a valid response back.

This is the URL: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&language=en&latlng=37.332596,-122.030319

I have tried this on a simulator and 1 actual device. The app is good on the device but this problem occurs on the simulator. Documentation states that the quota is 2,500 per 24 hours but I am well below that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get current location's coordinates? Simulator might return `0.0, 0.0` in that case, and `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&language=en&latlng=0.0,0.0` returns ZERO_RESULTS.

Comment: I dont think I was getting a 0.0, 0.0 coordinate from the simulator. I logged the request url and it was the one in the question.